Spring Boot Starter OAuth2 Client - how to keep a user authenticated even after browser closes [ google oauth2 ]
I have a Spring Boot backend that uses the spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client in order to have a google oauth2 login system for my site.
Here is the SecurityFilterChain, when a user signs in with google, it adds the user to my database. GoogleOAuth2 user is a custom OAuth2User i made that exposes attributes like "email" more easily.
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())

                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/",  "/oauth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login
                        .userInfoEndpoint(userInfoEndpoint -> userInfoEndpoint
                                .userService(googleOAuth2UserService)
                        )
                        .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
                                throws IOException, ServletException {

                                GoogleOAuth2User googleOAuth2User = (GoogleOAuth2User) authentication.getPrincipal();
                                userService.processOAuthPostLogin(googleOAuth2User);
                                response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:3000");
                            }
                        })
                );

        return http.build();
    }

I then have an endpoint that my authenticated client calls to check if it is signed in
@GetMapping(path = "/authenticated")
    public User getAuthenticatedUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal GoogleOAuth2User principal) {
        return userService.getAuthenticatedUser(principal);
    }

On the frontend, I have a button that goes to the google oauth2 page.
<div>
        With Google: <a href="http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/google">click here</a>
      </div>

However, the problem I have here is that the client is only authenticated in the current browser session. When I close the browser and reopen it, the client is once again signed out and not authenticated. How do I persist the session so that my user is still "logged in" even after the browser closes?

OK apparently it was very simple. It doesn't require spring session or anything. Just add this to your application.properties
server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age=3600

3600 = cookie lasts for 1 hour
